# How to configure a specific subdomain in Apache as an exception to a general redirect?

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a website that runs on http and https and the http apache conf file is setup as follows so that (from what I understand) all requests redirect to the root of the https version of the website.

I want to make the subdomain test an exception to this so that the non secure http://test.example.com url is handled differently and hosts some pages.   Is there a way of defining an exception in the main http conf file?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAlias example.co.uk
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried creating a new conf file for my test subdomain but it seems to be ignored once it's been added to the apache live configuration.

```
UseCanonicalName On
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.example
    ErrorLog /var/www/test.example/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/test.example/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your configuration looks right and should give the result you want. Can you verify from the access log that requests to http://test.example.com are being answered by the right virtual host? Do you get the same result with curl as with a browser?

Comment: Hi @AndrewSchulman , the access log file is created in the url I specify but it's empty, 0 bytes.  I understood that the 'Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/' line in the original conf script may be overriding any subdomain specific query I have or is that likely not the case ?

Comment: The Redirect is contained within the virtual host for www.example.com, so it shouldn't apply to test.example.com. As you found in the log, the problem seems to be that the request isn't going to test.example.com - it's going to www.example.com, which if it's the first one, is the default when none of the others match.

Comment: Ok so sorry how do I change this so that it isn't ignored ?

Comment: Not clear, unless you show us your actual domain name and configuration.

Comment: Can I just check, the original domain config in the first sample above is defined in a file called 000-default.conf.   And then the new subdomain config is in test.example.com.conf.   Is that ok?  Does the name of the file have any influence on anything?